# ConfigureContainer in .NET Core 3.1 Generic Host implementation

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, autofac, autofac-module, microsoft.extensions.hosting

I am trying to migrate our framework project to .NET Core 3.1. 
As part of the migration, I am trying to register modules via ConfigureContainer method provided by the GenericHost.
This is what I have:

```
Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseServiceProviderFactory(new AutofacServiceProviderFactory())
.ConfigureContainer<ContainerBuilder>(builder => builder.RegisterModule(new 
                         WorkerServiceDependencyResolver.WorkerServiceDependencyResolver()))
```

And my WorkerServiceDependencyResolver has the following:

```
builder.RegisterModule(new FirstModule());
builder.RegisterModule(new SecondModule());
```

But when I do it this way, my application doesn't run, it starts without any error, but doesn't do anything.

But If I write it this way (this is how we had in .NET Framework):

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterModule(new FirstModule());
builder.RegisterModule(new SecondModule());
_container = builder.Build();
```

Everything works as expected when I explicitly build the container, but my understanding was that we do not need that in .NET Core?

Any inputs are greatly appreciated.

Cheers!

Comment: You can refer to this: https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/aspnetcore.html

Comment: I am looking for incorporating into .NET Core self hosted console app and also I have given as per the steps mentioned, but doesn't seem to register successfully without building the container explicitly @YongqingYu

Answer (score 1):

By specifying to the `IHostBuilder` that the *Service Provider Factory* is an `AutofacServiceProviderFactory`, it allows you create to a method right inside your `Startup` class, called `ConfigureContainer` which takes the `ContainerBuilder` as a parameter.

This is how you would instantiate the `IHostBuilder`. Nothing fancy, just following the *ASP NET Core guide*.

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseServiceProviderFactory(new AutofacServiceProviderFactory())
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        {
            webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
        });
```

Then, in the `Startup` class, add that method.

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration) => Configuration = configuration;

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // ...

    public void ConfigureContainer(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        // Here you register your dependencies
        builder.RegisterModule<FirstModule>();
    }

    // ...
}
```

Then, your `IContainer` will be the *IOC Container* of your *ASPNET Core* application scope.
Notice than the builder is not being built at any time. This will be done by the `IHostBuilder` at some point (making use of the *Autofac* extension).

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi @VRoxa, Mine is a Console application and not an ASP.NET Core application. I have followed the same steps in mine, if you see the post, but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @vroxa When do you register something in the ConfigureContainer with Autofac vs. registering a singleton in the ConfigureServices method?